# How to send credentials from DevTools in a Chrome extension to a custom Werkzeug-based server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, credentials, werkzeug

In my chrome extension I want to send credentials from my custom DevTools panel to a locally running custom Werkzeug-based server. My request to the server looks like:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// let rType = "GET";
let rType = "POST";
xhr.open(rType, loadPath, true, login, password);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();
```

The server gets this request and even sends the data I want back to the extension.

The problem is that I can find no sign of the credentials I sent in Werkzeug's Request server-side object. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper investigation and numerous attempts I have revealed that the correct request to the server should look like:

```
xhr.open(rType, loadPath, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa(login + ":" + password));
xhr.send();
```

So to succeed you have only to set the request header explicitly. Both `login/password` parameters in `xhr.open()` and `withCredentials` property of `xhr` play no role, `rType` may be both `"GET"` and `"POST"`.

The same is true for `fetch(obj)` method, the pair

```
header: new Headers( { "Authorization": 'Basic ' + btoa(login + ":" + password) } );
```

should be added to `obj`.

If a server send back a response with a cookie, added for example with a method like `set_cookie()` from Werkzeug/Flask, the browser accepts and stores this cookie successfully.